# AngularJS $http.get difference between then and success callback

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like understand the difference between then callback and success callback when called over http get. When i use then callback it returns the data but with success callback it doesnt. Below is the code

**Then callback**

```
$http.get(url).
  then(function(response) {
     response.data.data;});
```

**Success callback**

```
$http.get(url).
   success(function(response) {
     response.data;});
```

Answer (score 6):

Your issue seem to be around this:

> $http.get('/someUrl').   success(function(**data**, status, headers,
>   config) {

it's a different return from `then`,

> `then` method to register callbacks, and these callbacks will receive
>   a single argument – an object representing the **response**

In other words, you should be doing this:

```
$http.get(...).success(function(data){ console.log(data) })
$http.get(...).then(function(response){ console.log(response.data) })
```

And of course the chaining differences, but doesn't seem related to your issue:

### `then()`

If you chain `then()`, the callbacks will run *sequentially* after each one is done, because it returns a new promise object on each chain

### `success()` (deprecated* along with `error()`)

If you chain `success()` calls, the callbacks will be ran in *parallel*, because it returns the original promise object

*`success` and `error` are deprecated, see *Deprecation Notice* section in [$http docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

Comment: Some corrections to the code that I posted.   users = function() { return $http.get(url).
     success(function(response) {
      return response.data;}) }                users = function() { return $http.get(url).
   then(function(response) {
     return response.data;}) }

Comment: when do console.log inside the callback function both of them print the data but only then returns the data and not success callback.

Comment: @Vaishu13, both can be used as per your requirement. I'd say in above code of yours, reponse.data is not valid while using success call back. In success callback your "response" parameter directly contains data. Above code of yours is true for then() callback.

Comment: yes you are right in my success callback response contains the data but only thing is why doesn't it return data for success callback but it returns data for then callback

Comment: This function return value is used to populate a form element.

Comment: I am primarly trying to understand the difference between the two pieces of code that I have posted because with the then callback it works as expected but success doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

you can use any of .then or .success and the call back code depends on what method you are using.

.then() will have two arguments first is the success handler and second is the error handler.success handler inside then() can be written in some other way nothing but .success.the main diffrence between successhandler inside then() and .success function is .success will have 4 arguments(data,status,headers,config) where as success handler in then() will have only one argument which has(data,status,headers,config) embeded in that one argument nothinf but you can access it like(response.data,response.status etc...)

Answer (score 0):

Important recommendation from [angularjs.org](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#get):

**The $http legacy promise methods success and error have been deprecated**. Use the standard then method instead. If `$httpProvider.useLegacyPromiseExtensions` is set to false then these methods will throw $http/legacy error.